# Switch Statement with char always returns 0 in C

Tags: c, char, switch-statement

For some reason the switch statement always returns a value of zero, the input values are correctly matched in the switch but for some reason the return values default to zero, making colorx = 0. Thanks for help in advanced.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


double  Band(char code);

int main()
{
char     code1, code2, code3, code4, code5;     
double  resistance;
double  color1 = 0, color2 = 0, color3 = 0, color4 = 0, color5 = 0;  
int     flag, Lines, i;
FILE *ifp, *ofp;
//char outputFilename[] = "C:\\Users\Kevin\\Desktop\\resistorOutput.txt";
ifp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\resistorInput.txt", "r");
//ofp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\resistorOutput.txt", "w");

rewind(ifp);
fscanf(ifp, "%d\n", &Lines);
for(i=1; i<=Lines; i++)
{
printf("Lines = %d\n", Lines);
fscanf(ifp, "%c%c%c%c%c\n", &code1, &code2, &code3, &code4, &code5);
printf("code1 = %c\n", code1);
printf("code2 = %c\n", code2);
printf("code3 = %c\n", code3);
printf("code4 = %c\n", code4);
printf("code5 = %c\n", code5);
color1 = Band( code1);
color2 = Band( code2);
color3 = Band( code3);
color4 = Band( code3);
color5 = Band( code3);
printf("color1 = %d\n", color1);
printf("color2 = %d\n", color2);
printf("color3 = %d\n", color3);
printf("color4 = %d\n", color4);
printf("color5 = %d\n", color5);
}
}


double Band(char code)
{
printf("Switch Code = %c\n", code );
switch ( code )
      {
case 'A':{
      printf("case a\n");
      return 0.0;
     }
case 'B':{
     printf("case b\n");
     return 1.0;
     }
case 'C':{
      printf("case c\n");
      return 2.0;
     }
case 'D':{
      printf("case d\n");
      return 3.0;
     }
case 'E':{
      printf("case e\n");
      return 4.0;
     }
case 'F':{
      printf("case f\n");
      return 5.0;
    }
case 'G':{
      printf("case g\n");
      return 6.0;
    }
case 'H':{
      printf("case h\n");
      return 7.0;
    }
case 'I':{
     printf("case i\n");
     return 8.0;
   }
case 'J':{
      printf("case j\n");
      return 9.0;
    }
case 'K':{
     printf("case k\n");
     return 10.0;
    }
case 'L':{
      printf("case l\n");
      return 11.0;
    }
default:{
      printf("case default\n");
      return 11.0;
        }

}
}
```

Comment: It is not returning 0, you are printing double as ints.

change 

printf("color1 = %d\n", color1);

to 

printf("color1 = %lf\n", color1);

Comment: @Sayutee , `%f` is better than `%lf` there.

Comment: @Sayutee, Why didn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: I would have picked yours as an answer @Sayutee but you didnt post it as one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler says very clear:

```
1.c:40:25: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
printf("color1 = %d\n", color1);
```

The switch works well, the function  `Band()` probably returns the correct values but they are `double` and you try to print them as integers.

Change the `printf()` format from `%d` to `%f` and it will work.

Also note that the `color4` and `color5` are computed using `code3` and this is probably not the intention but a copy-paste mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I see that your function returns double type but when printing you use "%d" which is for integer printing. Use %f or %lf (Not supported by ISO C) for printing double type. For me here it works correctly.

Comment: `%lf` is standardized since ISO C99.

Comment: I "ate" 90 after the C letter. Thanks !  I referred to C90 , unless you specify the compiler to consider C99 or C11 .